# passing List<String> as a parameter

Tags: java

I have a function

```
public class PlayerManager {
    public PlayerManager(List<String> players){
    //something to manipulate the player list..
    }
    private static class PlayerNode {
      public String name;    
      public PlayerNode next;
      //...
    }
}
```

What I need is to create PlayerNode(it works like a LinkedList) in the constructor based on the data in the player list.  What comes to my mind is to create an array and then iterate it and create the PlayerNode List:

```
String[] playerArray = players.toArray(new String[players.size()]);
```

But the assignment requirement says I can't construct any arrays, ArrayLists, LinkedLists, Stacks, Queues, or other data structures.

So my question is if I can not create any class implemented List interface. How can I handle the data in it?

Thanks

Comment: First start by explaining what you mean by "handle the data"--and what would an array give you that a list doesn't?

Comment: In your example, you are creating an array. Not being able to use any data structure at all really puts you in a bind. What are you trying to do with the data?

Comment: A `List` is generally a more useful data type than an array. Why do you need to convert it?

Comment: If its about converting `ArrayList<String>` to `String[] array`. Then `String[] playerArray = new String[players.size()];
playerArray = players.toArray(playerArray);` You can access the string array like `for(String s : playerArray)
    System.out.println(s);`

Comment: You don't need to convert `players` to anything. Just start calling the methods specified in the `List` interface. You won't violate your assignment restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the sounds of it, you are going to be passing some sort of list into your method, so you could just do something like this:

```
public class PlayerManager {
    public PlayerManager(List<String> players){
         for(String player : players){
             //do something with your player
         }
    }
}
```

This will allow you to do something with the list of players without knowing what data structure you are going to be using.

Comment: Thank you. But why can I directly use a list without instantiating a class implementing it?

Comment: Whoever/whatever is calling the PlayerManager constructor has already instantiated some kind of list and then passed it in via the "players" parameter. You don't know exactly what list implementation it is (ArrayList, LinkedList etc), but you know it is some kind of List, and so you can treat it as a List and as such you can use basic lowest-common-denominator List functionality with it.